# Minimize a function in two variables with constraint

Tags: optimization

I have to minimize this:
\begin{align*}
\min&\quad{ (x-3)^2+(y-1)^2} \\
s.t.& \quad 2x+y \leq 2 \\
&\quad x^2 + 2y = 3\\
&\quad x, y \geq 0
\end{align*}
Can I isolate $y$ in the second constraint and substitute it in the first?

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable approach. But before you do this, I'd recommend drawing a picture to help you understand the geometry of this problem.

Comment: @Neal I would say that's a circle with center (3,1) and the feasible region is the partial parabola under the line $2x+y-2$, but according to wolfram the function is a paraboloid

Answer (score 1):

Let $$(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2=z~~~(1)$$ Let us put $x^2=(3-2y)$ in (1), we get $$y^2-4y-6x+13-z=0.~~~(2)$$ $z$ will attain optimum value if when the line $y=2-2x$ touches the curve (2)
which is a parabola. Let us but this line in (2)
$$4x^2-6x+9-z=0.~~~~(3)$$
Now demand $B^2=4AC$.This gives $z=27/4,$ the answer.

Comment: If we put $x^2=(3-2y)$ in (1) don't we get:
$x^2+9-6x+y^2+1-2y=(3-2y)+9-6x+y^2+1-2y=y^2-4y-6x+13-z=0$?
And following your calculus with the line $y=2-2x$:
 $(2-2x)^2-4(2-2x)-6x+13-z=4+4x^2-4x-8+8x-6x+13-z=4x^2+2x+9-z=0$ and here we have a negative $\Delta$.

Comment: @ValentinaSau I have re-checked to find that my steps are right!